# Mailchimp and httpstatus.io returning a 500 error

Tags: http-status-codes, webp, srcset

Mailchimp and httpstatus.io are returning a 500 error on a URL, but the page is displaying correctly in all the browsers I've tried & the status code when fetching the page using cURL is 200.

Having done some testing, I've narrowed this down to images & using secset/webp images.

For example, when the image is specified as the below, httpstatus.io returns a 500 error:

```
<img src="/oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-850.webp" srcset="/oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-800.webp 800w, /oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-640.webp 640w, /oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-320.webp 320w" alt="">
```

The same is true for the following:

```
<img src="/oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-850.jpg" srcset="/oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-800.webp 800w, /oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-640.webp 640w, /oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-320.webp 320w" alt="">

<img src="/oimgnn/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-850.webp" alt="">
```

But when the image is simpified to the below, httpstatus.io returns a 200 status:

```
<img src="/img/HD_104_8cc70ae9797774642027c6dd45645e5a-850.jpg" alt="">
```

I can confirm ALL the images are available as specified... any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis was an issue in my script... the server didn't have the $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] variable which I was using to check that webp images were accepeted. A simple isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) fixed it!